# “Each PHP statement must be on a line by itself” Sonarqube pattern error

Tags: php, sonarqube

I'm analyzing a PHP code using Sonarqube, and I've noticed that in almost all files I have this error:

"Each PHP statement must be on a line by itself" (DisallowMultipleStatementsSameLine)

But when I check this files seems that there is no error.

For example, in this file the error is raised:

```
<?php
/**
 * Category of the question
 */
class Category {
    public $categoryId;
    public $name;
}
?>
```

How can be?

Comment: Wonky line ending characters?

Comment: you dont really need the `?>` on the end, infact now-days its bad practice to do so.

Comment: But probably completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the line endings. Changing the line endings to "Linux line endings" makes the problem disapear

Comment: Correct Answer.

Answer (score 7):

As google brought me here -> same issue is reported when there is a double semicolon on the end of the line, like `someCall();;`.